# Why are my resources not getting copied in the "validate" phase?

Tags: maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am trying to make sure that the correct resources are moved to `WEB-INF/config/` no matter if I call

```
mvn gcloud:deploy
```

or

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

which is why I am enforcing `-Dpackage-mode=<value>` to be set. I am using the `maven-resource-plugin` for the copy part like this:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>validate</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/assembly/${package-mode}/config</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However, if I run

```
mvn validate tomcat7:run -Dpackage-mode=dev
```

for starting the server the files are not getting copied.

```
E:\java\mz\mz-server\mz-web-server>mvn validate tomcat7:run -Denv=dev -Dpackage-mode=dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mz-web-server 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-property) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ mz-web-server >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-property) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ mz-web-server <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ mz-web-server ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at E:\java\mz\mz-server\mz-web-server\target\tomcat
[INFO] setting SystemProperties:
[INFO]  gwt.codeserver.port=9876
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath:
Jun 03, 2016 5:24:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jun 03, 2016 5:24:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jun 03, 2016 5:24:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
...
```

What am I doing wrong here? I actually don't know if `validate` is a good choice here and I am not really bound to a certain phase. All I want is to make sure that the configuration files are getting copied according to `package-mode`.

**But:**

If I just run

```
mvn validate -Dpackage-mode=dev
```

then everything is working as expected - the files are getting copied.

Comment: @A.DiMatteo I've tried to add it but it's the same :/ I updated my question mentioning that the way I put it up there works if I just run `mvn validate -Dpackage-mode=dev` without problems. It's just not working if I try to `validate` first and then `tomcat7:run` ..

Comment: I saw your update and deleted my comment, which indeed was not valid any longer. you actually don't need to use the `-am` option, it's mean for multimodule projects when building certain modules and not the whole project. the `skipTests` option should not influence at all your invocation neither. During the first try, what output do you get from the build? starting from `[INFO] ---- maven-resources-plugin ... ` for its `copy-resources` goal?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo Added the output to my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy webapp resources, this plugin is only for application resources. Furthermore, you should *never* generate or copy files under `src`, like what you're doing with `<outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config</outputDirectory>`. Generated files should always be placed under the `target` folder.

Instead, use the [`maven-war-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). You can configure it to [filter a specific directory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) and output it in the WAR like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <webResources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/assembly/${package-mode}/config</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <targetPath>WEB-INF/config</targetPath>
      </resource>
    </webResources>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will filter the directory `src/main/assembly/${package-mode}/config` and place the files under it in the target folder `WEB-INF/config` in the WAR.

With this change, you will be able to run your webapp with `mvn clean tomcat7:run-war` (and not `tomcat7:run` since that wouldn't package the WAR).

Comment: "*in the target folder WEB-INF/config in the WAR*" - I see .. it is not copying this stuff into `src/webapp/WEB-INF/config` .. those files are just moved into the WAR file. Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: @displayname Yep exactly. Glad I could help!